# variable 'alert' is written to, but never read

Tags: swift

I have an alert-box, which returns a number of warnings that I'm having trouble, getting rid of.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Delete the group?", message: "The group is removed permanently", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { [weak alert] (_) in
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { [weak alert] (_) in
    // Perform the serverside action here and dismiss
}))

self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Both addAction-lines returns a "Variable 'alert' is written to, but never read"-warning. I don't understand, since I use it in the "present"-line in the same scope.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should add the appropriate language tag for more visibility.

Comment: What is the `[weak alert]` for? Delete it in both cases.

Comment: Perfect - much appreciated. I didn't see the point in the "weak alert" either, but I'm still inexperienced in Swift...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have all my alerts in a separate class like so;

```
class AlertViewController {    
    func someAlert(with title: String?, message: String?, viewController: UIViewController) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let someAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Action Title", style: .default) { (_) in
            //Perform your action here
        }
        alertController.addAction(someAction)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        viewController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

If you use the `style: .cancel` it will automatically dismiss the alert.  Furthermore, as a better UX, including this `.cancel` will allow the user to tap anywhere on the view to dismiss the alert as well.

You can call this action where needed like so;

```
AlertViewController.someAlert(with: "Title", message: "Message", viewController: self)
```

Self is the `UIViewController` you wish to present upon.

Comment: All alert buttons dismiss the alert regardless of their style. There's nothing special about the `.cancel` style in this regard.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Regarding the cancel-action, I used the same code-template from another project, where I had to do a server side call as well, when clicking the cancel-button.